# Sync button on Github Desktop (mac) not working

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I am using GitHub Desktop app on my mac. I am using the enterprise edition of github. I am signed in the app and the browser. I am able to pull in changes using the github app. I also see changes show up when I am adding code to my local repo. But I am unable to sync the changes.

When I click the "Sync" button, I get the Authentication Failed error, its very weird as I am definitely signed in, to be able to pull the changes and also have access to the repo.

I have tried both my company password as well as the username + github personal access token combination for the password too.None resolved this issue.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-cloning the repository from your enterprise github.

Comment: Do you have to pay to get an enterprise account. Does GitHub Desktop work with a free Github account?